# How can I search a hackage package for a function?

Tags: haskell, hackage

Maybe I am missing something, but is there a way to search inside some package on hackage?

Let's say I know that Snap framework has a function called `render`. How do I find it starting on it's hackage page:
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-0.9.0.1

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) for this (as for so many other things) by using the `+package` search operator.

By default, Hoogle will search inside a standard set of packages by name or by type:

- [Searching for `traverse`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=traverse) will find:

  - [`traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Traversable.html#v:traverse)
    [base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/) [Data.Traversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Traversable.html#v:traverse)
  - [`traverse_ :: (Foldable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f ()`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html#v:traverse_)
    [base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/) [Data.Foldable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html#v:traverse_)
    Map each element of a structure to an action, evaluate these actions from left to right, and ignore the results.
  - … and so on
- [Searching for `(a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=(a+-%3E+b+-%3E+c)+-%3E+f+a+-%3E+f+b+-%3E+f+c) will find:

  - [`liftM2 :: Monad m => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m r`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM2)
    [base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/) [Control.Monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM2)
    Promote a function to a monad, scanning the monadic arguments from left to right.
  - [`liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2)
    [base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/) [Control.Applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2)
    Lift a binary function to actions.
  - … and so on

Now, that's fine and dandy, but what about other packages?  If you [search for `render`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=render), you find [`Render :: RenderMode`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/OpenGL/latest/doc/html/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-GL-Selection.html#v:Render) from [OpenGL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGL/), [`render :: Doc -> String`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pretty/latest/doc/html/Text-PrettyPrint-HughesPJ.html#v:render) from [pretty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pretty/), and some other things; the snap package isn't searched by default.

However, if you add `+packagename` or `+Module.Name` to your search, Hoogle will *only* search inside the specified packages (and `-packagename` and `-Module.Name` remove packages/modules from the search).  Thus, [searching for `+snap render`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%2Bsnap+render) finds only the following three things:

- [`render :: HasHeist b => ByteString -> Handler b v ()`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap/latest/doc/html/Snap-Snaplet-Heist.html#v:render)
  [snap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap/) [Snap.Snaplet.Heist](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap/latest/doc/html/Snap-Snaplet-Heist.html#v:render)
  Renders a template as text/html. If the given template is not found, this returns empty.
- [`renderAs :: HasHeist b => ByteString -> ByteString -> Handler b v ()`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap/latest/doc/html/Snap-Snaplet-Heist.html#v:renderAs)
  [snap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap/) [Snap.Snaplet.Heist](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap/latest/doc/html/Snap-Snaplet-Heist.html#v:renderAs)
  Renders a template as the given content type. If the given template is not found, this returns empty.
- [`renderWithSplices :: HasHeist b => ByteString -> [(Text, SnapletSplice b v)] -> Handler b v ()`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap/latest/doc/html/Snap-Snaplet-Heist.html#v:renderWithSplices)
  [snap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap/) [Snap.Snaplet.Heist](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap/latest/doc/html/Snap-Snaplet-Heist.html#v:renderWithSplices)
  Renders a template with a given set of splices. This is syntax sugar for a common combination of heistLocal, bindSplices, and render.

For more information on using Hoogle, you can [check its manual on the Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hoogle).

Comment: Wow, I've been using hoogle all the time, and never knew I could do this!

Comment: Nice! If you're looking for something, and you don't even know what package it is in, you can also use [hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html).

Comment: @DanBurton Thanks, but it didn't find the render function in Snap.

Comment: @drozzy does for me searching [render snap](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html#0:render%20snap). If you just search for [render](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html#0:render), there are 11 pages of results, and it's in there too, just not on the first page.

Comment: @DanBurton Oh d'oh, I didn't see 11 pages of results. I thought there was just the one. Nevermind!

Comment: How come some packages return no results like `+megaparsec`?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: I think the Hackage hoogle hasn't updated recently/for a while, but I forget where I read that.  The data does seem consistent with that, though…

Answer (score 7):

Click on the link to some module in the package. Then in the top right, there is an [index](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap/0.9.0.1/doc/html/doc-index.html) link. Click on that, and then on the link to the letter with which the desired function begins.